Move Apple account from one family to another
Can someone explain the impact / process for moving an adult Apple account from one family group to another?
I am astonished that I can’t find any clear answer from a Google search - surely this is a common thing to want to do?
In particular, if the account has more than the base level iCloud storage used, what happens to that storage during the (brief) period when the account is in neither family?
One of the answers to this question:
Upgrade iCloud storage from 50gb to 200gb then downgrade?
Suggests that basically it wouldn’t be possible to push more data while the account is briefly over capacity - that wouldn’t be a problem, provided no data is lost and things work normally again from the point of joining the new family group.
Thanks

I would strongly recommend that you simply purchase the needed storage for one month to avoid issues.

We went ahead and did the move, and it worked as hoped. The account went in to an “over capacity” warning when we left the first family, but that cleared and no data was lost when we joined the new family (and hunted down the “use family storage” option).

Got it - glad it worked. To address your remark about being able to buy storage before leaving the family, you should be able to do so. But in this case you're all set.

You are correct, when you no longer have available storage space left you can no longer push new data to the cloud.
This can happen for a few reasons, one as you have described by leaving a family that has extra storage space.
Typically, you have a grace period of time to upgrade your storage capacity. However, if you are over the limit. Apple does have the right to start purging data to free up storage space for those who are paying, but that typically takes a few months before they will start that process.
One important detail is that if you use iCloud email, that email storage is directly connected with your iCloud storage limit. If your iCloud storage is full you may not receive any new email during that time. If this is an issue for you, I would recommend once you leave the family to purchase additional storage for your self until you join the new family.
Also keep in mind that there is a certain limit to how many times you can leave and join another family within a specific period of time.

You can only join one family at a time, and you can only switch to a different family group once per year. This is a quote from the bottom of this page. link

Thanks for your answer - based on the confirmation we went ahead and did the move. As the gap between being in the two families was as short as we could make it, it made no sense to buy storage to cover that short time, especially as it probably wouldn’t have been possible to do so until the first family was left, when any problem would already have happened.
